# How to remove item from pagedList

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-paging-library

Hi i am using mvvm and paging library.
Pagination works perfectly.

i want to remove item from list.

when i try remove item

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.waalapp, PID: 21397
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
        at com.example.waalapp.ui.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:73)
        at com.example.waalapp.adapter.WaalAdapter$WaalViewHolder$1.onClick(WaalAdapter.java:66)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

My Activity

```
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, Waal waal,int pos) {
                waalPagedList.remove(pos);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Can we see the definition of a `waalPagedList`, please?  What is it?  How do you instantiate it?  How is `remove` defined?

Comment: PagedList<Waal> waalPagedList;

Comment: `waalViewModel.userPagedList.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<Waal>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PagedList<Waal> waals) {
                waalPagedList = waals;
                adapter.submitList(waals);
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

PagedList does not support remove operation, it is immutable list.

Comment: How can I remove the element from the list? There is no list in my Adapter class